# api request parameter with ION

Tags: android

I want to send json object as parameter using ION library as mentioned blow request parameter

```
{ "key":{
         "mobile":"94xxxxxxxx",
         "status":"Active",
        },
  "IP":"127.0.0.1",
  "name":"device"
}
```

if it is not possible with ion then please suggest me another way.

Answer (score 0):

use Ion.with(MainActivity.this).load("type","url").asJsonObject()
......
....